# DataTables Filtering Array of Objects by attribute and not by array Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to create a date range filter that can be applied to a number of datatables. The problem I am having is even though I am passing 
in my aaData value as an array of objects by the time I get to the filter function it is in an array.  This wont work because the index of the date value in the array is different in the various dataTables throughout my application and I would much rather be able to do it via dot notation on an attribute something like this.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var iMin = document.getElementById('start-datepicker').value;
            var iMax = document.getElementById('end-datepicker').value;

            // Create Minimum Date Object
            var iMinDate = new Date(iMin);

            // Create Maximum Date Object
            var iMaxDate = new Date(iMax);

            // Create Date Column Object
            var iDateStr = aData.date;
            var iDate = new Date(iDateStr);

            if ( iMinDate < iDate && iDate < iMaxDate )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
```

my initialization is similar to this http://live.datatables.net/iyavud/7/edit#source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a hack but it seems to work got the data via the oSettings.aoData object and the iDataIndex argument.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var iMin = document.getElementById('start-datepicker').value;
            var iMax = document.getElementById('end-datepicker').value;

            // Create Minimum Date Object
            var iMinDate = new Date(iMin);

            // Create Maximum Date Object
            var iMaxDate = new Date(iMax);

            // Create Date Column Object
            var rowData = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex]._aData;
            var iDateStr = rowData.date;
            var iDate = new Date(iDateStr);

            if ( iMinDate < iDate && iDate < iMaxDate )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
```